# SSRS Max Row Value across all columns

Tags: reporting-services

I'm busy with a report to show maximum value for a group, however when I do a MAX function I only get the the same result as the current row and I require it to be the same/highest MAX value in all rows. I need to do this on the report itself as the data set is MDX.

As you can see below, I require the max column to be 67% on all the rows.

[Report Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtLJs.png)

Comment: It's not clear how you are calculating the percentage. Have you tried an expression in this form: `=Max(Fields!ColA.Value / Fields!ColB.Value)` ?

Comment: Hi. The percentages come from a data warehouse. However, I don't really care if it's percentages or just normal amounts, I'm not able to get the highest max amount to show in all columns.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the scope in your expression, something like

```
=Max(Fields!ColA.Value / Fields!ColB.Value, "myDataSetName")
```

or

```
=Max(Fields!ColA.Value / Fields!ColB.Value, "myColumnGroupName")
```

Without seeing the full design I can't tell you what it should be but the first option above would give you the max amount over the entire dataset and the second example would show calcuate this within the columngroup.

Comment: Thanks, did not work 100%, however it point me in the right direction. I had to use the tablix name. =Max(Fields!ColA.Value / Fields!ColB.Value, "Tablix1")